# In Docker, do I need to publish ports if I set network to host?

Tags: docker

I was running into an issue today where I have a Dockerfile that `EXPOSEs` several ports and I wanted to run it with the `--net=host` flag.

However, all connections to the ports that the container was supposed to be listening on were refused.

Running `docker inspect` on the container I noticed this:

```
        "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": {},
        }
```

Growing exasperated I deleted the `--net` flag all together and went to the default `bridge` network. Surprise it works!

```
    "Ports": {
        "8000/tcp": null,
    }
```

Except now it has this strange `null` setting. What is the difference here? Also, plot I'm running inside of a VM trying to communicate with another VM. Probably a million reasons this won't work.

Comment: It could be down to a firewall on the host perhaps? You shouldn't have to publish anything when running on the host network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question

> Is the publish option needed when the network mode is `host`?

### Answer

No, the host network stack is directly used by the container:

> `'host': use the Docker host network stack. Note: the host mode gives the container full access to local system services  such  as  D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.`

### Proof

#### Start a container with `netcat`:

```
user@host:~$ docker run -it --rm --net host nc:1.10-41
root@container:/# nc -l -p 9999
```

#### Back into the host:

```
user@host:~$ nc 127.0.0.1 9999
Sending a message for test <enter>
```

The message will be displayed from the `netcat` command executed within the container.

#### Monitoring

A  `netstat` from the host will show the established connection:

```
user@host:~$ netstat latuep |grep 9999
tcp        0      0 localhost:38600         localhost:9999          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:9999          localhost:38600         ESTABLISHED
```

---

### As for your issue

The error may stem from another configuration/network environment. Can VMs ping each other? Do they share the same LAN? Is a firewall set?

Comment: Great answer! Yes, they can ping each other. They're also on the same VLAN. It might be some oddity with BOSH lite. They use some kind of container system to mock VM creation.

Comment: Also could you provide a link to that doc? I knew I saw that yesterday, but couldn't find it again.

Comment: I just did a `docker man run`. Lot of options are available if you did not skim yet it you should ;)